# Why does the following overriden method return Promise<HTTPResponse<Buffer>> when responseType argument isn’t set?

Tags: typescript

```js
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from "http"

type Method = "POST" | "GET" | "PATCH" | "PUT" | "DELETE"

type Headers = {
  [key: string]: string
}

type JSON = {
  [key: string]: any
}

type ResponseType = "buffer" | "json" | "text"

interface HTTPRequest {
  method: Method
  url: string
  headers?: Headers
  qs?: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
  json?: JSON
}
interface HTTPRequestOptions {
  headers?: Headers
  responseType?: ResponseType
  retry?: {
    limit?: number
    methods?: Method[]
  }
}
interface HTTPResponse<T = unknown> {
  statusCode: number
  headers: IncomingHttpHeaders
  body: T
  request: HTTPRequest
}

class HTTP {
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions & { responseType: "buffer" }
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse<Buffer>>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions & { responseType: "json" }
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse<JSON>>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions & { responseType: "text" }
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse<string>>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse> {
    return this.send(
      {
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        json: json,
      },
      options
    )
  }
}

const httpInstance = new HTTP()

;(async () => {
  // Why is `response1` of type `HTTPResponse<Buffer>`?
  const response1 = await httpInstance.post(
    "https://api.example.net/hello"
  )
  // The following behaves as expected (`response2` is of type `HTTPResponse<JSON>`)
  const response2 = await httpInstance.post(
    "https://api.example.net/hello",
    null,
    {
      responseType: "json"
    }
  )
})()
```

Comment: Because it matches first overload

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL.. Just figured out that using `?` (`json?` and `options?`) in overloads is the problem.

Comment: Yes `?` makes them optional

Comment: @AlekseyL. Wish to submit and answer or should I answer the question myself?

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit.

Had to remove the `?` in the overloads.

```js
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from "http"

type Method = "POST" | "GET" | "PATCH" | "PUT" | "DELETE"

type Headers = {
  [key: string]: string
}

type JSON = {
  [key: string]: any
}

type ResponseType = "buffer" | "json" | "text"

interface HTTPRequest {
  method: Method
  url: string
  headers?: Headers
  qs?: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
  json?: JSON
}
interface HTTPRequestOptions {
  headers?: Headers
  responseType?: ResponseType
  retry?: {
    limit?: number
    methods?: Method[]
  }
}
interface HTTPResponse<T = unknown> {
  statusCode: number
  headers: IncomingHttpHeaders
  body: T
  request: HTTPRequest
}

class HTTP {
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options: HTTPRequestOptions & { responseType: "buffer" }
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse<Buffer>>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options: HTTPRequestOptions & { responseType: "json" }
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse<JSON>>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options: HTTPRequestOptions & { responseType: "text" }
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse<string>>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse>
  public post(
    url: HTTPRequest["url"],
    json?: HTTPRequest["json"],
    options?: HTTPRequestOptions
  ): Promise<HTTPResponse> {
    return this.send(
      {
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        json: json,
      },
      options
    )
  }
}

const httpInstance = new HTTP()

;(async () => {
  // Why is `response` of type `HTTPResponse<Buffer>`?
  const response1 = await httpInstance.post(
    "https://api.example.net/hello"
  )
  // The following behaves as expected (`response` is of type `HTTPResponse<JSON>`)
  const response2 = await httpInstance.post(
    "https://api.example.net/hello",
    null,
    {
      responseType: "json"
    }
  )
})()
```